# horizontal slide with 100% width with jcarousellite

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I am using jcarousellite control to provide carousel effect on my images via next and prev button.

```
<button class="prev"><<</button>
<button class="next">>></button>

<div class="anyClass" style="background-color:Red;" >

    <ul style="width:100%">
        <li style="width:100%" ><div style="background-color:Green; width:100%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;" ><img src="Untitled-1.jpg" /></div></li>
        <li style="width:100%"><div style="background-color:yellow; width:100%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;" ><img src="Untitled-2.jpg" /></div></li>
        <li style="width:100%"><div style="background-color:Green; width:100%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;" ><img src="Untitled-1.jpg" /></div></li>
        <li style="width:100%"><div style="background-color:yellow; width:100%; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;" ><img src="Untitled-2.jpg" /></div></li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want them to expant as far as the width of the browser. Width : 100%. This is not working for some reason.

I guess the question would be how do I have 100% width of `<li>` so that it can expand till the end of the screen.

=========================

## update

if i set width:105% on anyclass then it is giving full width. However once I go on bigger screen it again gives issues...please help

Comment: You want the images to be 100% width as well?

Comment: no just the div...wish i could attach the screen shot

Comment: image should be in the center of the div and div should be 100%...so when i slide the div by clicking next...whole div including the image inside of it would slide...this way i can get smooth transition...i am able to do this ...problem is 100% width

Comment: You need to quote those angle brackets in the button text, like this: "&lt;&lt;" for "<<" and "&gt;&gt;" for ">>". That's important, though not your major problem here.

Comment: What exactly does the `<div>` style look like? Does it have padding? A border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using another plugin

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure it will work, but try

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

in your CSS

Comment: can you mount a simple HTML demo online? it would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had to add li and ul with 100% with and no paddin no margin...that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.jcarousel')
    .on('jcarousel:create jcarousel:reload', function() {
        var element = $(this),
            width = element.innerWidth();

        if (width > 900) {
            width = width / 1;
        } else if (width > 600) {
            width = width / 1;
        }

        element.jcarousel('items').css('width', width + 'px');
    })
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();
```

Comment: 'If' condition can be modified according to your requirement